# Error log if number is not within range of other worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having some trouble writing my VBA macro which does the following:

In cell C3 I will entered a cost center and in cell D3 there will be a cost type number entered.

Now what I want to do is display an error message that pops up, when the value in C3 starts with 3 and the value in D3 (always 7 numbers) is NOT within the rage of numbers listed in cells AG2:AG23 of another worksheet called metadata.

My code so far is the following:

```
'Do While...

    '...

    If Left(Cells(CLine, 3).Value, 1) = "3" Then

        If Cells(CLine, 5).Value = blank Then
            If SLine = 1 Then
                ErrLog = ErrLog & "Costcenter in Line" & " " & Dline
                SLine = SLine + 1
            Else
                ErrLog = ErrLog & ", " & Dline
            End If
        End If

    End If

    Dline = Dline + 10
    CLine = CLine + 1

Loop

If SLine > 1 Then
    ErrLog = ErrLog & " requires WBS Element." & vbCrLf
End If
```

Now if I expand the first line like this `If Left(Cells(CLine, 3).Value, 1) = "3" and Left(Cells(CLine, 4).Value, 7) <> "1000000" Then` it works fine and my error message will only come up when another Value than 1000000 is entered in the Cell D3.

But as soon as I start to use things like <1000000 and >2000000 (in order to not get the message when a number between 1000000 and 2000000 is used), I get error after error.

Can someone help me and tell me how to include a "Between" in in the first line of my code in an easy way, so that I get no error as soon as a number between 10000000 and 2000000 is entered?

Comment: trying to indent your code you have a `Loop` where is the `Do While` or other start statement ?

Comment: The problem is that I'm trying to expand the formula of an existing file. The Loop starts further down the way, but that's a whole bunch of code.

What I would like to do to maybe not explain it in VBA code would be the following check:

If the Value in Cell C3 starts with 3 and the Value in cell D3 is not in the range of Cells AG2:AG23 of the worksheet Metadata, then the error message "please enter a WBS element" should appear

Comment: Are your values in Column D formatted as Numbers ? Id yes, there is no use to `Left(Cells(CLine, 4).Value, 7) <> "1000000"` just use `Cells(CLine, 4).Value <> 1000000` or `Cells(CLine, 4).Value > 1000000`

Comment: Yes, they are formatted as numbers. What I'm having trouble with is the "between" part since the error needs to only appear when I enter a number smaller than 8000000 or bigger than 9000000, but not when I enter a number between 80000000 and 9000000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can define your Range that you want to check if Cell D3 is inside the values like this:

```
Dim Rng     As Range

' set-up check range (modify Sheet name and Range to your needs)
Set Rng = Sheets("metadata").Range("AG2:AG23")
```

Second, to display an error message when Cell C3 starts with "3", and Cell D3 value is outside that range use the line below :

```
  If Left(Cells(CLine, 3).Value, 1) = "3" And _
    (Cells(CLine, 4).Value < WorksheetFunction.Min(Rng) Or _
    Cells(CLine, 4).Value > WorksheetFunction.Max(Rng)) Then
```

And third, to check if a certain cell is Blank (or empty) change your line :

```
If Cells(CLine, 5).Value = blank Then
```

To :

```
If IsEmpty(Cells(CLine, 5)) Then
```

Comment: This is great and seems to work partly. It does give me the error when I enter a number with 3 or 4 numbers that is smaller than 8000000 but if I enter one higher than the max in my range, it still doesn't give me the error which is strange since I'm sure your Code should work

Comment: Oh I've just seen it only gave me another error message from further down the code road... I will have to check why this won't work... I have one other problem which I discovered with the new error... I can't format the cost type numbers as numbers since the Vlookup won't work if I do... So there text and I probably should check with the code if the value is in my range, but the then the min/max thing won't work, right?

Comment: It works! It fist didn't to due to my own stupidity. I can't even copy/past :-) Probably been working on this file to long and made two "and" instead of one "and" and one "or" as you did... Thank you so much for your help!